# Digital temperature meter probe wire length

Tags: digital-logic, measurement, temperature, thermistor, probe

I bought a cheap Chinese digital thermometer like this one

with this description [Link to product](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1M-Thermometer-Hygrometer-Temperature-Meter-Digital-LCD-Display/32780313103.html?spm=2114.40010208.4.44.XCxq2C)

> Item specifics
>
> ```
> Power Type: Button Battery
> Model Number: Thermometer
> Max Measuring Temperature: 50°C - 69°C
> Style: Handheld
> Theory: Temperature Controller
> Display Size: 2.0 - 3.9 Inches
> Display Type: Digital
> Usage: Indoor
> ```
>
> Product Description
>
> Feature:
>
> ```
> 100% brand new and high quality.  
> Quantity: 1   
> Measuring temperature range: -50Celsius~110Celsius
> Temperature accuracy: ±1 Celsius  
> Temperature display resolution: 0.1 Celsius   
> Operating voltage: 2 x 1.5V button LR44 batteries
> Dimension: 48×28.6×15.6mm(approx.)    
> LCD dimension: 36×16mm(approx.)   
> Operating Voltage: 1.5v, LR44/AG13(Include    
> Cable length: 1m  
> Color: Black
> ```
>
> Package Content:
>
> ```
> 1X Mini Thermometer Hygrometer Temperature Meter Digital LCD Display
> ```

It does not have a Hygrometer as far as I know.

I opened it up and found this
[image: Circuit board]

It has a probe wire length of about 1 meter. I wish to use it to find the temperature in the storage tank of a solar water heater about 20 meters away. My question is - can I just extend the wire (2-core wire) without affecting the temperature measurement? I looked up Amazon product reviews for similar products (not sure they are the same on the inside), but I didn't see any reviewers having extended the wire more than a few feet.

Also, what power supply can I use instead of LR44 cells. I cannot make out the chip inside, though some reviewers on Amazon have stated that anything upto 30 Volts would work.

Comment: Show the wire and the probe please.

Comment: @VladimirCravero - I had to remove the image because I cannot post more than 2 links. Use the first link above that takes you to the Aliexpress product listing which has the pic of the thermometer I'm talking about [link](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1A3HwJFXXXXbGXXXXq6xXFXXX3/New-Digital-font-b-LCD-b-font-Thermometer-for-Fridges-Freezers-Coolers-Chillers-Mini-1M-Probe.jpg)

Comment: It looks like a PTC. Do you have a multimeter? Can you measure the resistance of the probe?

Comment: That sensor could also be a DS18B20 digitial 1-Wire sensor, in which case the data is transmitted digitally over the power line as a series of pulses (shorts). I've got a few with 5 meter cords and fairly thin wires (think CAT5 network cable thickness) and that works fine. 20 meters may push the limit though, as resistance and capacitance of the parallel conductors of the extension cord could distort the signal too much.

Comment: @JvO Not sure about that - do you have a LCD display? All the ones that mentioned DS18B20 had LED displays for some reason. Came across 100 meters mentioned in some application note for the DS18B20

Comment: @VladimirCravero - seems like it is around 1M - (have to get a new battery for my MM). I could try putting an appropriate resistor in parallel to offset the resistance of the extension wire. But mostly if I know how hot the water is (so if it reads 25 and the water is actually 45 degrees), it will do for my purposes.

Comment: Well, my sensors are used in a totally different product. But LED vs LCD is irrelevant in this case; what is relevant if the probe is digital (like a DS18B20) or analog (PTC) I just mentioned it because from the outside the sensor looks a lot like the digital one. And 1 MOhm seems high for a PTC.

Comment: 1Meg is not a PT100. Where is the sensor connected to the board?

Comment: @VladimirCravero - I cut the wire and measured the resistance - 9.9 Ohms at approx 25 deg Centigrade and started falling rapidly when I held the probe in my hand. So it is a PTC. Extending the cable may be harder than I thought with the resistance so low.

Comment: xs400 I bet it was actually 9.9K. And dropping when you put it in your hand means NTC unless your hand is colder than room temperature.

Comment: You could try it and see, use a heavy gauge wire to minimise resistance error.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these devices use AC on the sensor (making the thermistor part of an RC circuit). In the case extending the probe will probably fail. The 1.5V operating voltage makes it much more likely it is such a chip. There also appears to be a 10K reference resistor beside the NTC thermistor connections, so it could be this type.

You can test it with a cable or by adding appropriate capacitors to the probe connections to simulate the cable capacitance. If your cable is 20pF-30pF per foot you might try 1nF.

If it is DC through a typical 10K @ 25 C thermistor you can extend it to any reasonable length- the wire resistance will have no significant effect.

Answer (score 0):

If current has to flow through the wires, you're definitely going to have an additional voltage drop. By how much? With this little information, I don't know. If the sensor's impedance is very high compared to that of 2x20 meters of wiring, then you don't need to worry about it. I'm leaning towards this possibility considering how the module is powered.

On the product info, it says "Operating voltage = 1.5V" but nothing about the max operating voltage. There is a way to find out, since we don't know much about the schematic nor the ICs. Try it yourself! Use a power supply which supports current limitation feature to limit the current in case the board tries to draw to much current and fry itself.